# Why is $\operatorname{Spec} \ k$ final in category of $k$ schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am working on an exercise trying to show that $Spec \ k$ is final in category of $k$ schemes.
I am stuck and I would appreciate any assistance. Thank you!

PS The definition I have for $k$ scheme is that it is a morphism of the form
$X \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} \ k$. And then I know from the exercise I did that
$X \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} \ A$ are in natural bijection with ring morphisms
$A \rightarrow \Gamma (X, O_X)$.

So I figured if I have a $k$ scheme, then it follows that
there exists a corresponding ring morphism $k \rightarrow \Gamma (X, O_X)$.
I guess I was wondering how this is unique.

Comment: Do you agree that $k$ is initial in the category of $k$-algebras?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I guess that is what I was confused about. Is it obvious that the map from $k$ to the global section of some $k$ scheme is unique?

Comment: Yes, there is a unique $k$-algebra homomorphism. That's the important thing!

Comment: @user211392: remember, it's not just a homomorphism of *rings*.  It's a homomorphism of $k$-algebras.  (If you don't see the difference, think about the $k$-algebra structure on $k$ itself and carefully unpack the definition.)

Comment: What is your definition of the category of schemes over $k$? The right definition makes this obvious (it's the category of schemes equipped with a map to $\text{Spec } k$; this is a very general construction called taking the overcategory, and the object you're taking the overcategory of is always terminal).

Comment: I have added PS to make my specific question more clear. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Does it follow from construction of the correspondence between $X \rightarrow Spec \ k$ and $k \rightarrow \Gamma (X, O_X)$ that it is in fact a $k$ morphism and not just a ring morphism? (The exercise I did only mentioned it was a ring morphism...)

Comment: You are using the wrong definition for a morphism of $k$-schemes.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. This whole thing makes a lot more sense to me now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A $k$-scheme is a scheme $X$ together with a morphism $X \to \operatorname{Spec} k$.  A *morphism* of $k$-schemes is a morphism $\varphi : X \to Y$ of schemes such that the diagram
$$\begin{array}{c}
X & \xrightarrow{\varphi} & Y \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
\operatorname{Spec} k & = & \operatorname{Spec} k
\end{array}$$
commutes.  In particular, not every morphism $\varphi : X \to Y$ of schemes is a morphism of $k$-schemes.  This appears to be the sticking point for you.

(This is just an unpacking of what Qiaochu Yuan mentioned in the comments.)

Comment: I see. Thank you. So then in the exercise I did which states "show that morphism $X \rightarrow Spec \ A$ are in natural bijection with ring morphisms $A \rightarrow \Gamma (X, O_X)$" are they referring to just morphisms of schemes or morphisms of $k$ schemes (or are they equivalent in this case?)

Comment: @user211395: morphisms of schemes. If you want morphisms of schemes over $k$ on the left then that corresponds to $k$-algebra morphisms on the right.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!